How to use flags-dir to automate sf cli commands (for example sf package version create)?
What is the expected file & directory structure in order to use the --flags-dir flag?
I am trying to create a package version and I would like to use flags dir configuration.
for example I have added 3 different files:

installation-key with the passcode inside
installation-key.json with the passcode inside
installation-key.txt with the passcode inside

Also, do I have tried to use as a value inside those files:

installation-key=<secret here>
<secret here>

On the other hand there are other flags like the single char 'p', 'w', 'f'. How to setup them as well?
There are other flags without values required like the '--verbose' flag. How to setup that one as well?
I also want to setup a long description with multiple lines inside. As I have a demo package for our managed package I want to show a short list of files included in the example. How to add multiple lines for the '--description' flag into that very same approach?

I have 2 different packages(a managed and a demo for the 1st), so I want to have 2 different configs for building each package.

After creating a ticket and waiting for some time. SF added documentation on the topic: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_flag_values_in_files.htm
